# Connect to OSX via IIS7.5 in Parallels with UNC path

Tags: macos, authorization, iis-7.5, unc, parallels

I have IIS7.5 with ASPNET 4.0 running in a Parallels virtual machine on Windows 7 on an external harddisk which I connect to my MacBook Air. 
My website source files are on my MacBook Air. I want to configure a website within IIS7.5 that points to the files on the MacBook Air. I now have this under physical path ('Basic Settings...' in IIS): \psf\home\dropbox\inetpub\mysite
My username and password for Windows 7 and OSX are the same.
But when I enter those credentials under 'Connect as', it does not work when I click 'test settings'. Authentication is checked, but Authorization failed with "Path might not exist and could not be verified (\psf\home\dropbox\inetpub\mysite)".
When I enter the UNC path in Windows Explorer directly I'm able to view the files.

How can I configure this correctly?

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not. I just created a separate image on an USB3.0 SSD drive and worked completely in a Windows VM.